# Meteor, image upload not working on live website

Tags: meteor, meteor-collections

I am using cfs:s3 and before that I tried cfs:dropbox to store images. When I run the app locally it works fine but when I deploy it on meteor.com it stops to upload the image to either one of the platforms.

Any known issues to this?

```
var imageStore = new FS.Store.S3("playerProfilePictures", {
accessKeyId: "", //required if environment variables are not set
secretAccessKey: "", //required if environment variables are not set
bucket: "mohsinclubimages", //required
transformWrite: createThumb //optional
});


PlayerProfilePictures = new FS.Collection("playerProfilePictures", {
stores: [imageStore]
});
```

The policy for S3

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "s3:ListBucket"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
    },
    {
        "Action": [
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:PutObjectAcl",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:GetObjectAcl",
            "s3:DeleteObject",
            "s3:DeleteObjectAcl"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::mohsinclubimages/*"
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Any console errors to work with?

Comment: No I am not getting any console errors. You can test the form here http://holmlia-cc.meteor.com/admin

Comment: I get this warning in the console: `The provided value 'undefined' is not a valid enum value of type XMLHttpRequestResponseType.` when trying to upload

Comment: Also, check server side logs. I don't know how the dropbox package works and what it's trying to do on upload

Comment: I have replaced dropbox store with s3 store. I will edit the question to include the code. This warning I am getting on local machine as well.

Comment: the reason an upload might work on local is because the server has access to the folder it's trying to upload to, whereas on the meteor.com servers, this might not be the case

Comment: Where do I set the access rights then?

Comment: I don't know if that is the issue. You should have a look at the github issues for the cfs packages. It's def come up before. Also if it doesn't work with s3 either it might be another issue

Comment: I assume you've set the correct access key and info for s3 right?

Comment: yes I think so, because I am able to upload images through localhost.